# How can I do element-wise multiplication of two arrays when one element is derived by a formula?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, typeerror

I'm trying to multiply two arrays together element wise

```
expected_state = np.array([-1.004  0.002  0.0]) 
b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2], 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]])
```

Each element of `expected_state` should be multiplied postionally with every element from each row in `b`
So `[[-1.004*1.0, 0.002*0.0, 0.0*0.0], [-1.004*[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2], 0.002*0.0....etc]]`

Array `b` is defined in a function so that the first element in row two can change as `stoch_rate` and `popul_num` change as the program executes.

```
def update_matrix(popul_num, stoch_rate): 
    """Specific to this model 
    will need to change if different model 
    implements equaiton 24 of the Gillespie paper"""
    b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2], 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 
0.0], [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]])
    return b
```

So far I've used nested for loops to try and do the multiplication:

```
for j in range(len(evaluate_propensity)):
    for i in range(len(popul_num)):
        denominator[j] += (exptd_state_array[i]*b[j, i]) # TypeError: Cant multiply sequence by non-int type "numpy.float64"
```

But get the TypeError: `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'`

I've had a look at some other posts which say things like this happen when trying to multiply list indecies with non-integers because list indecies can't have partial numbers. Which I understand but the elements of my arrays are meant to be floats so I'm not too sure how to over come that.

Then after reading some more, I found that the error came when the program was trying to do the multiplication of the `[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2]` element from array `b` and was wondering if the `TypeError` would come from that formula derived element of the array and if it does how could that be fixed?

Cheers

EDIT:

```
popul_num = np.array([1.0E5, 0, 0]) # array of molecule numbers for 3 species in model
stoch_rate = np.array([1.0, 0.002, 0.5, 0.04]) # rates of the 4 reactions in the model 
evaluate_propensity = np.array(a, b, c, d) # An array of the probability of each  reaction occuring, is dynamically calculated on each iteration so isn't hard coded.  

exptd_state_array and expected_state are the same thing sorry forgot to change the short hand
```

Comment: Hi, the code you posted does not give the error you posted. this is because you do not define `evaluate_propensity, popul_num, stoch_rate, exptd_state_array, denominator` and possibly others that I have missed. Could you complete the code?

Comment: what is the shape of denominator?

Comment: `[1,2,3]*2.0` produces this error.  List replication requires an integer

Comment: @warped 'denominator = np.zeros(len(evaluate_propensity))' so its got the same shape as evaluate_propensity (4,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
popul_num = np.array([1.0E5, 0, 0]) # array of molecule numbers for 3 species in model
stoch_rate = np.array([1.0, 0.002, 0.5, 0.04]) # rates of the 4 reactions in the model 
evaluate_propensity = np.array((.25,.25,.25,.25)) # An array of the probability of each  reaction occuring, is dynamically calculated on each iteration so isn't hard coded.  
denominator = np.zeros(4,)

expected_state = np.array([-1.004,  0.002,  0.0]) 
exptd_state_array = expected_state
b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2], 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]])

b

array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [list([199.999]), 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

so, b has mixed types. The list is generated by the  square brackets around  `[stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2]`

Multiplication for lists is defined as concatenation with itself: `3 * [5] = [5, 5, 5]`. This fails with floats, as @hpaulj pointed out in the comment.

leaving out the square brackets:

```
b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]])

b 


array([[  1.   ,   0.   ,   0.   ],
       [199.999,   0.   ,   0.   ],
       [  0.   ,   0.5  ,   0.   ],
       [  0.   ,   0.4  ,   0.   ]])
```

Then, the double loop does execute